# EventBus.post() within Service, how to call function from Thread.BACKGROUND

Tags: android, service, event-bus

I'm trying to implement a function which will make some clean up when user is closing app ( Swiping off ) .

inside Activity.class

```
  @Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.BACKGROUND)
    public void stopSearching(MyService.StopSearching stopSearching)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "stopSearching: ");

    }
```

MyService.class

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Started");
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d("ClearFromRecentService", "Service Destroyed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
        Log.e("ClearFromRecentService", "END");
        EventBus.getDefault().post(new StopSearching());
        stopSelf();
    }

    public class StopSearching {
        StopSearching() {
        }
    }
}
```

But I get:

> EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class
>   com.talkie.ashaneen.firebaseapp.other.MyService$StopSearching
>
> EventBus: No subscribers registered for event class
>   org.greenrobot.eventbus.NoSubscriberEvent

Comment: Is your `Activity` in the foreground when this event is posted?

Comment: @Napster this code runs when I have app minimized and swiping it away

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you must have unregistered the event bus when your `onStop` function is called. When your app is minimised, its in on stop stage, hence your Activity can't receive any events. I dont think you can perform anything event from background thread in this case, because your activity is removed from the memory and it can't receive any callbacks even from an EventBus.